# Can I render force.com page template based on a url parameter?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, dynamic-visualforce

Using a force.com site - Is there a way to select the visualforce page template using a URL parameter?

Use case: 
Our business partners want to send their clients to a co-branded page - including logo and possibly some custom text.

So what I am trying to do is change the template based on the url parameter.

I thought about displaying or hiding a logo based on the url parameter, but thought that could become unwieldy depending on the number of partners.

I am open to any other suggestions. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: How about creating a dynamic custom component, referencing the same in your VF template and controlling all the logic in controller? I have never come across such requirement but I am pretty sure this can be handled through this. Need to do lot of work though.

Comment: https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm    https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Dynamic_Visualforce_Components

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, I hadn't heard about dynamic components until I was tagging this post... I'm going to look into that right now, although "need to do a lot of work" doesn't sound much fun.

Comment: Yeah right... :) 
In fact I will look into the same. Seems like a good learning experience.

Comment: For sure. I *am* here to learn, after all.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, we can utilize EmailTemplate object to query the required template. There is a field on this object  - "TemplateType" that determines if the template is HTML/Text or Custom VF. We can then use DeveloperName field of this object to get the templateId, assuming you already know the mapping of template corresponding to parameters.

In the VF template, we can reference like this if most of the parts of the email are same. We can pass the attribute to the component and then to component's controller if the logic to display data on the template is complicated.

`<c:Name_of_component attribute_1="{!RelatedTo.id}"/>`

For regions that are variable, we can handle them in the VF template itself. We can then send the VF template through email using Messaging.sendEmail(). You must be aware if the setTemplateId() method to set the id of this VF template (which we know beforehand). This design would be good if there are not much VF templates. If the template count is large, then we may need to give more thoughts over this. I hope you get my idea.